# How to submit the form having two submit buttons to two different controller actions in grails

Tags: grails, jquery

I have a form captures the some data and after that i want to execute action "generatehtmlreport" ,if user clicks on generate html report button and another button will display ,on clicking this button ,the controller action "generatepdfreport" should execute and the main thing is the html report data should not go. here is the form i have

```
<g:form name = "report_generation" id ="report_generation">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "report_type" class = "report_type" value = "${reportType}"/>
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="form_legend">${reportTitle}</legend>
      <div class="dialog">
        <g:render template="/templates/filterTemplate" />
          <div class="cb"></div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id = "report_buttons">
      <input type = "submit" value = "Generate Report" class="td_link" name ="generate_report_html_btn" id = "generate_report_html_btn"/>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Export as PDF" style="display:none" class="td_link pdf_button" name ="generate_report_pdf_btn" id = "generate_report_pdf_btn"/>
    </div>
</g:form>

<div id = "html_report_section"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [g:actionSubmit](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) tag:

```
<g:form>
   // your fields
   <g:actionSubmit action="generateReport" value="Genereate Report" />
   <g:actionSubmit action="exportAsPDF" value="Export as PDF" />   
</g:form>
```

Comment: the problem with this is ,after clicking on "Export as PDF" button ,it is displaying some junk values are displaying not the pdf ,and i want this "export as pdf" request to be ajax call.

Comment: On clicking the "export as pdf" the displayed html report should not go .its should be there but the .how to make this "export as pdf" to cll controller method which generates pdf file as independent call using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your original question didn't specify you wanted the form submit to be an Ajax call. To call different Ajax actions in the same form I've used RemoteLink tags:

```
<g:form>
   // your fields
   <g:remoteLink action="generateReport" >Genereate Report</g:remoteLink>
   <g:remoteLink action="exportAsPDF" >Export as PDF</g:remoteLink>
</g:form>
```

Check the Grails documentation for RemoteLink's other properties and examples.